# compare ISO date (only day and month) with current date in mongoose with find query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

need a find query without aggregation for comparing iso date(only day and month part) with the current date in mongoose.....

db.xxx.find({ "$where" : function() { return 'UserDtls.dob'.getMonth() == 8 } } )

I need something like above

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine   [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$UserDtls.dob" }, 7] } })
```

It returns only 7th-month data, working fine MongoDB 3.6

or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$project: {month: {$month: '$UserDtls.dob'}}},
 {$match: {month: 7}}
]);
```

Comment: But i have mongodb 3.4 . please try something else

Comment: check that one more query but you need to project whatever you want. otherwise, you need to upgrade your MongoDB

Comment: i cannot use aggregate and same cannot upgrade mongodb

Comment: assign two variables called start and end start as month start date and end as month end date it's possible with moment js and query with those dates

Comment: example 

var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

firstDay = moment(firstDay).format(yourFormat);
lastDay = moment(lastDay).format(yourFormat);

db.coll.find({"UserDtls.dob" : {"$gte" : firstDay},{"UserDtls.dob" : {"$lte" : lastDay}}})

Comment: its not working beacause date of birth have different years other than current year.. i have already checked the same

Comment: You need to upgrade your MongoDB version or use aggregation framework.